# How to post some json data to a route in api

Tags: node.js, angular, express, npm, postman

I've created a very simple API in NodeJs. Here is the code:

```
const Post = require('../models/article');
...
router.post('/contribute', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Pushing new article');
    let userPost = req.body;
    let post = new Post(userPost);
    post.save((error, registeredPost) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(registeredPost);
        }
    })
})
...
module.exports = router;
```

The structure of a Post is this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const articleSchema = new Schema({
    articleid: String,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: String,
    contributor: String,
    upvotes: Number,
    upvoters: [String],
    downvotes: Number,
    downvoters: [String]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('article', articleSchema, 'articles');
```

Here is **server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const api = require('./routes/api');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api', api);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Server is up and running!');
})

app.listen((3000), function() {
    console.log('Server listening on heroku environment port');
});
```

Ideally the data should come from an angular form/template but before pushing the code I wanted to test this on Postman. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I'm getting:

> Cannot POST /contribute

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: have you added `app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));` in index.js ?

Comment: Have you exported your router in route file `module.exports = router;` ?

Comment: @TalESid, Yes I did.

Comment: Can you please share your route file & index.js

Comment: I'm adding my index.js code. Actually In my case it is **server.js**

Comment: This only happens when POST route `/contribute` can't be found!

Comment: I don't have any separate route file

Comment: then why are you using `router.post`? If there's no separate route file, use `app.post` in index.js

Comment: Ok @TalESid, thanks for pointing this out. I'm improving. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using:

```js
app.use('/api', api)
```

So, make sure to use this endpoint:

```
localhost:3000/api/contribute
```

And now, it's will working fine.

Comment: Yes, I also just posted this answer. Maybe we figured out this simultaneously. I'm accepting your's since you made efforts. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that I'm hitting the wrong URL.

**Wrong:**

```
localhost:3000/contribute
```

**Correct:**

```
localhost:3000/api/contribute
```

This is working absolutely fine now and I'm getting correct json response from the server also.